# How to set DIFFICULTY-stages for a math game

Tags: android

I'm currently doing an basic math app. The app is very basic, the player is given an easy equation to calculate. For any correct answer scores will be added to the player. If incorrect it will reset to 0. I have set 3 game difficulty-stages: `Easy, Medium & Hard`. To be able to play `Medium-difficulty` the player has to finish the `Easy stage` - example by setting a certain amount of points needed to be reached to open the next level.

**Problem:** One way I tried was to set a "lock" in the `PlayActivity.java` in this piece of code:

```
        case R.id.mediumButton:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MediumActivity.class));
            break;
```

this by simply trying to pass data of the Current Score from the `EasyActivity.java` and then set a limit of ex. 50p by using the `if-statement`. This would then prevent `startActivity(new Intent(this, MediumActivity.class));` from getting executted until the points are achieved. But I couldn't get the codes correct so that I could pass Current Scores from the `EasyActivity.java` to `Playactivity.java`.

Since I got nowhere with the above I tried another approach to this problem. I tried instead to use the `High Score` data stored (check below). Of course this is not the full code, just showing for context to give you guys a hint of what I did. **Any ideas?**

```
case R.id.mediumButton:
    int score = 50p
    if (score > highscore)
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MediumActivity.class));
break;
```

.

**SOLUTION:**
By using the shared preferences, which stores my highscore in the HighScoreActivity, I retrieved the data and used that with an if-statement to set a "lock" for Medium & Hard stage. This is the code I used (I also added a toast to inform the player about the conditions for the different stages):

```
    case R.id.mediumButton:
        if (storedEasyHighScore >= 150) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MediumActivity.class));
        } else {
            Toast mediumButtonToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LEVEL LOCKED!\nEASY-level: Min. 150p required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            TextView toastMessage = (TextView) mediumButtonToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            toastMessage.setTextSize(20);
            mediumButtonToast.show();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.hardButton:
        if ((storedEasyHighScore >= 150) && (storedMediumHighScore >= 300)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HardActivity.class));
        }else{
            Toast mediumButtonToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LEVEL LOCKED!\nEASY-level: Min. 150p required.\nMEDIUM-level: Min. 300p required.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            TextView toastMessage = (TextView) mediumButtonToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            toastMessage.setTextSize(20);
            mediumButtonToast.show();
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In easy activity whenever calling playActivity pass the current score.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, playActivity.class); 
  intent.putExtra("key",value);
  startActivity(intent);
```

In PlayActivity.java get score and initialize it:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 int score= intent.getIntExtra("key")
```

Comment: Could you tell me more precisely where to put the codes? Regarding the `intent.putExtra("key",value);`, in the value field, should I just write a "0"?

Comment: value is score   and key is used to access this score   `intent.putExtra("key",score);`

Comment: int score= intent.getIntExtra("key") - the key part is giving me error. I'm using the same key-name here as I did in the EasyActivity when passing it. I'm doing something wrong? Also should I place the code above for the "PlayActivity after this code (in my "onClick) case R.id.mediumButton:?

Comment: Now I got it to work. `int score= intent.getIntExtra("key")` had to add a ", 0" after the "(key)". But now another problem appeared. I've put an if-statement that looks like this:  
`int mediumDifficulty = 50`  

`case R.id.mediumButton:
    int score = 50p
    if (score > mediumDifficulty)
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MediumActivity.class));
break;`. Each time I answer an equation correct it suddenly throws me out from EasyActivity to the PlayActivity? [EDIT] How do you post this code properly on different lines? :S

Answer (score 0):

In PlayActivity.java, get highscore from sharedPref, set buttons Enabled(false) and set disabled button's color Color.RED:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....
   ...
   SharedPreferences sharedPrefsHighScore = getSharedPreferences("Prefs_HighScore",MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editorScore = sharedPrefsHighScore.edit();
   int storedHighScore = sharedPrefsHighScore.getInt("highScore",0);

   //fetching button id to work as button click
   Button easyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.easyButton);
   Button mediumButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediumButton);
   Button hardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hardButton);

   if(storedHighScore > 100) {
      mediumButton.setEnabled(true);
      hardButton.setEnabled(true);
      } else if(storedHighScore > 50) {
            mediumButton.setEnabled(true);
            hardButton.setEnabled(false);
            hardButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                     mediumButton.setEnabled(false);
                     mediumButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                     hardButton.setEnabled(false);
                     hardButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                     } 
   ....
   ...
   .
```

But I think best way is making Buttons invisible in XML and then check highScore and set visibility of buttons:

```
if(storedHighScore > 100) {
   hardButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mediumButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else if(storedHighScore > 50) {
          mediumButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. As I've already saved High Scores in another Activity using Shared Preferences. I assume I just retrieve the High Score in the PlayAcitivty by calling it and after set the code you posted above?

Comment: Best way is putExtra and getExtra as Robert said. Another way is set  highScore public , and get value anywhere you want.

Comment: I didn't really like the fact that the button completely dissapears. Prefere if it is there but not clickable. But thanks for the tip above. Really good to keep in mind for other projects.

Comment: By making it public you mean in the `Public Class` field? Mine is stored in the onClick from the `EasyActivity.java`, as you can see above. So where would you suggest to put the high score in that case?

Comment: Visible but unclickable button is not good for user experience. User can think that there is a bug in program.

Comment: Say if you store highScore in MainActivity, define highScore global: Public int highScore.Then you can access like: if(MainActivity.highScore >= 100)

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is only an excersise for my course that I need to hand in. So it's not that important if it is visible but not clickable :). Ok. It is stored in my HighScoreActivity, in one of my TextViews. I'll see if I get it to work.

Comment: Maybe you can use hardButton.setEnabled(false). But you must set different color or alpha value of disabled button.

Comment: I'm lost a bit, don't know how to make it Global. I'll just edit my codes above and post the entire `"HighScoreAcitivty"` as well, so you can see how it looks and maybe help me out a bit. EDIT: entered the codes for my "HighScoreActivity" as well.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `Private int` on top and `Public int` when getting the stored High Score? Also I unfortunately get the `Private int` gets greyed, says unused. Also when I try to call getstoredhighscore() in another acitvity it gives me following message: _Non-static method 'getStoredHighScore()' cannot be referenced from a static context_

Comment: Always on declaration of variables use Private, and on getter methods use Public. It is safe, it is [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). On the other hand, I changed my answer because of Non-static method error.

Comment: Now I'm recieving the same problem as before when I used an `if-statement`. When I go to the EasyActivity to play, after solving first equation and pressing my [ Correct ] button I get thrown out of the EasyActivity. Looking at the Android Monitor it shows this: `W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection`. Can't solve this problem, any ideas? Other than this, the .setEnable button if-statement works so far. Making them unclickable.

Comment: I have no idea about error. Can you past full error message, with line numbers? Does both correct and wrong answers throw error? Maybe you can ask a new question about error.

Comment: I guess after going through my entire code and fixing with minor details, somewhere and somehow the error has gone. I think it may have been connected to Shared Preferences or Passing Data intent. Not sure though. But everything is up and running perfectly and I could even use my initial idea of putting an `if`-statement to block the Medium & Hard buttons until a certain score has been reached. (For convinience I also added a toast - whenever a player presses Medium/Hard button it will inform the player what the requirements are to be able to play the different stages). Thanks for all the help